# Chrome, Firefox chromium Vivaldi starts up slow and greys out, online passwords not working either. 16.04

Tags: password, chromium, calendar, online-accounts

I don't know if it's two separate things but both started happening at the same time.

I noticed that my calendar was not being displayed any more up at the right-hand corner in Unity when you click the time (which I use all the time).

I also noticed that when I start Chromium it takes very long to start or it greys out when it starts to work. out of curiosity, I checked with Vivaldi and I'm seeing the same behaviour.

Also at startup, I have a sync program for nextcloud and it is unable to grab the password. This is the error I get from my nextcloud login at bootup

> Reading from keychain failed with error: `'could not open Wallet: other; failed to execute program org.kde.kwalletd: no such file or directory'`)

I also cannot delete online accounts or reactivate and it will also gray out for a period of time.

All these things just started today after a reboot. I went to take a print screen by hitting the print screen button I'm using the default program that came with Unity 7 when I hit my print screen button on my keyboard it takes roughly 30 seconds before it activates

What can I do about all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the following bug for this issue. Please add any relevant information and/or mark it as affecting you as well:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825